# 2 to the power of multiples numbers

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a method that takes a number and then puts every number between that and 0 as an exponent to the number 2.

**2^0 = 1**

**2^1 = 2**

**2^2 = 4**

**2^3 = 8**

**2^4 = 16**

This is as far as I've gotten. . .

```
def powers_of_two(n)
   n.map { |x| 2 ** (0..x) }
end
```

I believe I'm not far off in my attempt.

Answer (score 4):

For example, like this:

```
def power_of_two(n) = (0..n).each { puts 2 ** _1 }     
power_of_two(4)
#=> 1
    2                                       
    4                                       
    8                                       
    16
```

Comment: I expect that when computing powers with positive integral exponents, Ruby checks to see if the base number is `2`, and if it is then simply does bit shifting, meaning that `2 ** n` is just as efficient as bit shifting.

Answer (score 4):

You can build an enumerator that generates the numbers via [`Enumerator.produce`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce):

```
powers = Enumerator.produce(1) { |i| i * 2 }

powers.take(5)
#=>[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

The block generates each number based on the previous one, starting at `1`.

The same works for bit-shifting:

```
powers = Enumerator.produce(1) { |i| i << 1 }

powers.take(5)
#=>[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
```

Comment: Nice use of under-appreciated [Enumerator#produce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce).

Answer (score 3):

As we are dealing with powers of `2`, try this bit-shifting method. (I assume the given number `n` is non-negative.)

```
def po2(n)
  (0..n).each { |i| puts 1 << i }
end
```

```
po2(7)
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
```

See [Integer#<<](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3C) and possibly [this tutorial](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-use-the-bitwise-left-shift-operator-in-ruby).

---

One could alternatively create a proc.

```
po2 = Proc.new { |n| (0..n).each { |i| puts 1 << i } }
  #=> #<Proc:0x00007f91a5222bb0 <main>:0>
```

```
po2(7)
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
```